# Raspbian on Kindle Fire

Tags: raspbian

I know this is not a Raspberry pi question exactly but is it possible to install raspbian or emulationstation on a kindle fire tablet? I understand that there might be some hardware driver issues at first but I just want to know is it possible?

Comment: Welcome.  I've changed the title since the original question is [too broad](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).  Please take [the tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand better how the site works.

Answer (score 2):

You could not use the Pi kernel (which includes all the hardware drivers), but that is not a big deal since Raspbian is only tied to it in superficial ways.

Presuming you can compile or get a kernel for the Fire (which a quick look around implies *might* be possible; the Kindle OS is a version of Android and so uses a Linux kernel, the problem would be getting the proprietary bits), the Raspbian [userland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_space#Overview) *might* then work, since the fire is ARMv7 based.  However, there would not be much point in trying, since once you got to this point there is likely some more appropriate, near identical GNU/Liux distro.

If the general meaning of the above two paragraphs isn't clear to you, I strongly recommend you do not try this.